# Finding memory leaks through python process memory usage (windows7)

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I am trying to get memory usage of python process under win7 through a python script. So far i wrote a function to read the memory usage:

```
def analyseHostMemoryUsage(self):
    # return the memory usage of python process
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, False, os.getpid())
    memoryUsage = GetProcessMemoryInfo(handle)['PagefileUsage']
    win32api.CloseHandle(handle)
    return memoryUsage
```

I call this function after each iteration of a test script. Though in each iteration the same code is executed, the result of memory usage kind  of alternates (each line is for 1 iteration):

```
        Usage      diff
        24899584         -
        24862720    -36864
        24870912      8192
        24870912         0
        25182208    311296
        25182208         0
        25182208         0
        25182208         0
        25182208         0
        25182208         0
        25182208         0
```

im wondering about this output. When i run the script again i get a different output:

```
        Usage      diff
        25550848         -
        24895488   -655360
        24907776     12288
        24920064     12288
        25223168    303104
        25223168         0
        25223168         0
        25223168         0
        25223168         0
        25223168         0
        25223168         0
```

Can some one explain this? or maybe i read the wrong value ('PagefileUsage')?

Comment: > Can some one explain this? < depending on the run, process has different memory usage patterns.

Comment: so this means it is not useful to get an idea of memory leaks? can you explain in which pattern python process allocates memory?